# How to do the route?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to do the next drawing.
[image]

But, I can't do the route marked.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\def\side{1}

\foreach \j in {1,...,5}{

\begin{scope}[shift={(-60:\side*\j)}]

\foreach \i in {1,...,\j}{

\begin{scope}[shift={(0:-\side*\i)}]

\tkzDefPoint (0,0){A}

\tkzDefPoint (0:\side){B}

\tkzDefPoint (60:\side){C}

\tkzDrawPolygon[top color=LightSteelBlue4](A,B,C)

\end{scope}

}

\end{scope}

}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: After 88 questions a tip for you: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: If you wrote that code, it's difficult to imagine that you can't figure out how to draw the wiggly line....

Comment: JPi, I'm sorry, I didn't understand what you said. Can you be more clear?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `turtle` library can be of use here, although rewriting the "pyramid" code makes positioning the start of the turtle a bit easier:

```
\documentclass[border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{turtle}
\tikzset{turtle/.cd,
  S/.style={home, left=180},
  L/.style={left=60, forward},
  R/.style={right=60, forward},
  F/.style={forward}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line join=round, line cap=round, very thick]
\foreach \i in {0,...,4}
  \foreach \j [evaluate={\x=(\j*2-\i)*cos(30); \y=-\i*1.5;}] in {0,...,\i}
    \draw [shift={(\x,\y)}, top color=LightSteelBlue4]
       (90:1) -- (210:1) -- (330:1) -- cycle;
\draw [turtle={
      S, F, L, R, R, R, L, L, L, L, R, L, R, R, R, R, L, R, L, R, L
    }];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it's wonderful! I've seen very few examples of use of `turtle` library. Thanks @MarkWibrow!!